# adding port to net_sftp

Tags: php, ftp, sftp, net-sftp

I have a bit of PHP code that is responsible for logging into a SFTP server, it was working well before but now I need to add a port to the URL original code was as follows

```
   $sftp = new Net_SFTP('sftp.sftpurl.co.uk');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
}
```

I have read on other pages that I should adjust to the following:-

```
   $sftp = new Net_SFTP('sftp.sftpurl.co.uk', 2222);
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
}
```

When I run the php it comes up with "login failed" but if I use filezilla with the same credentials its loading the remote server without problems.

Any advice on how to get the php function to work in the same way as manual filezilla login?

Thanks

Comment: Your syntax is correct. So actually, you probably do not have a problem with *"adding port to net_sftp"*, but with authenticating. Post verbose phpseclib and FileZilla log files.

Comment: thanks for the response, give me around 30mins and I'll get it over, cheers

Comment: i have the filezilla log, can I message it to you as its saying there's too many characters to post

Comment: Post it to pastebin or similar site.

Comment: thanks...https://pastebin.com/ey2UEaZQ, thats the link it gave me, still trying to work out how to get the phpseclib output but will get it to you as soon as I can.